# PHP / MySQL on multiple servers. Good entry point

Tags: php, mysql

my first question here :)

Does somebody know a good entry point (good links/books) for webapplications shared on multiple servers? i want to know how to deal with data when i hava for example my site on installed on two servers + a mysql database on a third server.

I found several books regarding this topic but they are either to complex (wikipedia/facebook-like architecture) or are not dealing with PHP/MySQL. I'm not exactly a PHP beginner and  i am just interested in practical approaches to avoid inconsistencies etc.

Comment: Store your user-uploaded files centrally - set up replication between your mysql servers if you have more than one. Job done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is, there are multiple ways of doing it and you'll usually end up doing all of them.

One is to replicate your data on multiple servers. There are varieties of means to proceed (master-master using NDB, master-slave using InnoDB).

The other is to partition your data, in other words splitting a huge table in bite-sized chunks.

A subset of partioning is when your data can additionally be split into wholly independent chunks. In this case it might even make sense to break a few foreign key references and store them into entirely separate databases. For an example of this, see [WordPress/HyperDB](http://codex.wordpress.org/HyperDB).

Comment: Isn't there an additional time needed to keep a (distributed) database synchronized when writing to the db? What happens when i write alot into database and don't read alot (hypothetical). Isn't there an overhead?

Comment: There is indeed. But when you're in a very heavy write environment, you typically do so in memory tables, and then periodically persist it. (That's how telcos manage the billing of phone calls.)

Comment: Another question: Are the databases usually spread all over the world or for example in one datacenter. Shouldn't be reasonable to spread them on one hand over the world (international websites) but on the other hand keep them in one datacenter (ping/delay)?

Comment: I'm probably not the right person to ask, having never played with servers in a multi-datacenter environment. :-|

Answer (score 0):

learn about storing sessions in external places (i.e. memcache), distributed file systems, load balancing and reversing proxy (ie HAProxy), using database clusters, cache clusters (again memcache)